# Why can't I purge apache2.2-bin and apache2.2-common?

Tags: apt, delete, apache2

I have tried to completely remove apache2.2 from my system. But the only thing that happens is that apt-get will remove "apache2-mpm-prefork" and install "apache2-mpm-worker".

I have killed all apache processes and tried in both Synaptic. and apt-get from terminal. Why won't my system delete apache, and why will it install "apache2-mpm-worker"?

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what's the terminal output of such a failing try?

Comment: fluteflute below here was right. I didn't try to uninstall the whole package, only these "virtual packges". My problem is solved with my newfound knowlege!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: you need to purge the `apache2` package as well as `apache2.2-bin` and `apache2.2-common`.

Explanation: [this package is a "virtual package"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick-updates/apache2) - if you have it installed the system will make sure that one of `apache2-mpm-event`, `apache2-mpm-itk` or `apache2-mpm-prefork` or `apache2-mpm-worker` is installed. Note that these four packages themselves each depend `apache2.2-bin` and `apache2.2-common`.

Comment: You can also, usually for a sanity check, use a wildcard like "sudo apt-get remove apache2* " to see what relevant installed packages match.    I often run this with the -s  (simulate) just for safety.   Another way to find installed packages would be something like " dpkg --list | grep apache "